# Want event Listener to fire function only when text input field is populated

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I have a game that generates random answers to users questions. I want the eventListener to fire the “generateAnswer” function only when the text input field is populated.

```js
    const answers =['Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now', 'Don’t count on it', 'It is certain', 'Most likely', 'No', 'Outlook not so good', 'Outlook good', 'Signs point to yes', 'Very doubtful', 'Without a doubt', 'Yes'];
    
    const textInput = document.querySelector("#textInput");
    const clearBtn = document.querySelector("#clearBtn");
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    const h1 =document.querySelector("h1");
    const h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    
    // const generateAnswer = () => {
    // const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
    //         h4.textContent = answers[num];
    //         h1.append(h4);
    //     }

    function generateAnswer() {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
            h4.textContent = answers[num];
            h1.append(h4);
        }

    btn.addEventListener("click", generateAnswer);

    clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        h4.remove();
        textInput.value = "";
    });
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <h1>Magic Eight Ball</h1>
        
        <h4>Ask Your Question…</h4>
       
    <input type="text"id="textInput"><br>
        <div id="btnContainer">
            <button id="btn">Go for it</button>
            <button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "Populated"?

Comment: when someone enters a question

Comment: Put an `input` event listener on the text input.  If the value is empty, disable the button.  Otherwise you will have to add logic to your method to not do anything if the text input is empty.

Comment: @ppanasis, do you want the function to fire without the go for it button being clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as others said, if you need the function to only trigger when input is populated you would just need to add some logic to your generateAnswer function :

```
const generateAnswer = () => {
    // Converts input value length into a boolean
    const allowGeneration = !!textInput.value.length;
    
    // If no length (means input is empty, disallow answer generation)
    if(allowGeneration) {
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
        h4.textContent = answers[num];
        h1.append(h4);
    }
    
    // Bonus : Display error to user
    else {
        h4.textContent = "Please prompt a question before clicking on button.";
        h1.append(h4);
    }
}
```

However, if for some reasons you want the answers to be generated dynamically when input is prompted, you could do something like this :

```
// We add here a parameter to our function to only display error message
// when button is clicked (and input empty) and not when input is dynamically empty
const generateAnswer = (displayError) => {
    // Converts input value length into a boolean
    const allowGeneration = !!textInput.value.length;
    
    // If no length (means input is empty, disallow answer generation)
    if(allowGeneration) {
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
        h4.textContent = answers[num];
        h1.append(h4);
    }
    
    // Bonus : Display error to user
    else if(displayError) {
        h4.textContent = "Please prompt a question before clicking on button.";
        h1.append(h4);
    }

    // Else we just reset previous answer
    else {
        h4.remove();
        textInput.value = "";
    }
}

// We add a debounce function so that our function is not trigger every time a char is prompted
function debounce(callback, delay){
    var timer;
    return function(){
        var args = arguments;
        var context = this;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            callback.apply(context, args);
        }, delay)
    }
}

// Syntax changed a bit here so we could add our parameter
textInput.addEventListener('keyup', debounce(() => generateAnswer(false), 500))
btn.addEventListener("click", () => generateAnswer(true));
```

Answer (score -1):

pretty simple to do with a little javascript.  Just check the value attribute of the input box and wrap condition in if statement

```js
const answers =['Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now', 'Don’t count on it', 'It is certain', 'Most likely', 'No', 'Outlook not so good', 'Outlook good', 'Signs point to yes', 'Very doubtful', 'Without a doubt', 'Yes'];
    
    const textInput = document.querySelector("#textInput");
    const clearBtn = document.querySelector("#clearBtn");
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    const h1 =document.querySelector("h1");
    const h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    
    // const generateAnswer = () => {
    // const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
    //         h4.textContent = answers[num];
    //         h1.append(h4);
    //     }

    function generateAnswer() {
    
    var ifield = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
    
    if(ifield != ''){
    
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
            h4.textContent = answers[num];
            h1.append(h4);
    }
    }

    btn.addEventListener("click", generateAnswer);

    clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        h4.remove();
        textInput.value = "";
    });
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <h1>Magic Eight Ball</h1>
        
        <h4>Ask Your Question…</h4>
       
    <input type="text"id="textInput"><br>
        <div id="btnContainer">
            <button id="btn">Go for it</button>
            <button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: You didn't fix the problem. He wants the function to run every time it's changed. Your function is still only running when they button is pressed.

Comment: OP never says that, and besides that doesn't make sense.

Comment: He wants it to change also when the value inside the text input is changed. You didn't include that. He clearly said, "I want the eventListener to fire the “generateAnswer” function only when the text input field is populated." That means he wants to run that function every time the input's value is changed. You kept it the same, and now it only answers when you press the "Go for it" button.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation.  Let's ask the OP what he actually wants.

Comment: Okay. I asked earlier what he meant and he said he wanted a knew answer whenever a knew question is typed; or the input is changed.

Comment: there's no record of that being asked or answered

Comment: Look at the comments posted on the question.

Comment: you are stubborn. Let's wait and see if OP provides more info

Answer (score -1):

You can listen for the input event and react according to your needs. The part about 'the field is populated' may be as simple as checking the input's text length.

```
var txt = document.getElementById('textInput');

txt.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if(this.value.length > 0) {
    generateAnswer();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm correct, you want it to say something every time the value inside the input is changed. The code below catches when the input is changed. Once you click outside of the box with a new input, it'll give you the magic eight ball's reponse.

```js
const answers = ['Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now', 'Don’t count on it', 'It is certain', 'Most likely', 'No', 'Outlook not so good', 'Outlook good', 'Signs point to yes', 'Very doubtful', 'Without a doubt', 'Yes'];

const textInput = document.querySelector("#textInput");
const clearBtn = document.querySelector("#clearBtn");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
const h4 = document.createElement("h4");

function generateAnswer() {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);
  h4.textContent = answers[num];
  h1.append(h4);
}

textInput.addEventListener("change", generateAnswer);
btn.addEventListener("change", generateAnswer);

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  h4.remove();
  textInput.value = "";
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Magic Eight Ball</h1>

  <h4>Ask Your Question…</h4>

  <input type="text" id="textInput"><br>
  <div id="btnContainer">
    <button id="btn">Go for it</button>
    <button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why? The answer is changed whenever the input is changed. You just have to click out of the input when you are done typing so it looses focus, and it'll change.

Comment: If you are going to interpret it that way then as soon as 1 letter is change without clicking outside the box the function should fire which doesn't make any sense. secondly, if you do it your way what's the point of the go for it button?

Answer (score -2):

you can use either onchange or oninput, ie:

html:

```
<element onchange="myFunc">
```

js:

```
object.onchange = function(){myScript};
```

Comment: You should use the function generateAnswer() instead of `myFunc`.

Comment: I'm sure he can interpret that.